# Regexp Mysql test if odd characters match

Tags: mysql, regex

I have strings that are 6 characters in length and I need to test if the first character and third are the same, or the 1st and 5th or 3rd and 5th.  The strings contain letters and numbers

So

```
aabbcc --> false
abbcad --> true
aaabcd --> true
bacada --> false
1a1b33 --> true
```

I need this to be part of a mysql query.  Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest (and probably fastest) way is to compare the individual substrings:

```
SELECT str,
       SUBSTR(str, 1, 1) = SUBSTR(str, 3, 1) OR
       SUBSTR(str, 1, 1) = SUBSTR(str, 5, 1) OR
       SUBSTR(str, 3, 1) = SUBSTR(str, 5, 1) AS matching
FROM data
```

Output

```
str     matching
aabbcc  0
abbcad  1
aaabcd  1
bacada  0
1a1b33  1
```

If you are running MySQL 8+ you can take advantage of the enhanced regex capability to use back-references in the pattern:

```
SELECT str,
       REGEXP_LIKE(str, '^(.).\\1') OR
       REGEXP_LIKE(str, '^(.)...\\1') OR
       REGEXP_LIKE(str, '^..(.).\\1') AS matching
FROM data
```

Output is the same as the previous query:

```
str     matching
aabbcc  0
abbcad  1
aaabcd  1
bacada  0
1a1b33  1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fb46bd8fba9bde3269a436d527c0aa18)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring()`.

```
...
WHERE substring(nmuloc, 1, 1) = substring(nmuloc, 3, 1)
       OR substring(nmuloc, 1, 1) = substring(nmuloc, 5, 1)
        OR substring(nmuloc, 3, 1) = substring(nmuloc, 5, 1)
...
```